# Getting or Calculating Speed in WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I'm developing Apple Watch app like Workout app.
I can get distance, heartbeat and calories from workout.
But I'm not sure how can I get or calculate speed.

I tried to calculate speed every when distance value is obtained.
In that case, if user stop walking/cycling, app should display 0.0km/h. But didn't reach to 0.0.

I want to know how to get more accurate speed value.
Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to get the info? Please post some code.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/89733/healthkit-tutorial-with-swift-workouts
I used the code in this url.

Comment: Please post the code that you have to get the the info at your post, thanks.